# Aeson: derive some (but not all) fields of a struct

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I have a large struct which I need to be an instance of FromJSON so that I can parse my json data into it.

I would like to derive automatically, but a single field needs "special care" in that it is an object in json and I want it to be an array of the values in my struct. How can I do this without writing a huge FromJson implementation repeating all the fields?

Example json:

```
{"myobject": {"one": 1, "two": 2}, ...many_more_fields...}
```

Example struct:

```
data MyStruct = MyStruct {
  myobject :: [Int],
  ...many_more_fields,...
} deriving (Generic)
```

How do I do this elegantly?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53352563/haskell-aeson-is-there-a-better-way-of-parsing-historical-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a `newtype` for your special field:

```
newtype MySpecialType = MySpecialType [Int]

instance FromJSON MySpecialType where ....

data MyStruct = MyStruct {
      myobject:: MySpecialType,
      ...
   }
```

Now the instance for `MyStruct` becomes entirely regular and can be handed off to Template Haskell in the normal way.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid carrying the newtype from [Paul Johnson's very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53449107/6863749) all across the codebase, you can also generalize your type as follows, making the type of `myobject` a parameter:

```
data MyStruct_ intList = MyStruct {
  myobject :: intlist,
  ...
} deriving (Functor, Generic)

type MyStruct = MyStruct [Int]

instance FromJSON MyStruct where
  parseJSON = (fmap . fmap) (\(MySpecialType i) -> i)
            . genericParseJSON defaultOptions
```

`genericParseJSON` above gets instantiated with `MyStruct MySpecialType`, and then the field gets unwrapped via `fmap` (noting `MyStruct_` is a `Functor`)

---

I also just wrote a [blogpost about "type surgery"](http://blog.poisson.chat/posts/2018-11-26-type-surgery.html), applied to this kind of problem so that you can keep the original type unmodified.

[The generic-data-surgery library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-data-surgery) can derive a generic type with the same `Generic` structure as `MyStruct_ MySpecialType` above, to be used by aeson's `genericParseJSON`. The surgery `modifyRField` then applies the function `\(MySpecialType i) -> i` to the `myobject` field, finally yielding `MyStruct`.

```
import Generic.Data.Surgery (fromOR, toOR', modifyRField)

-- The original type
data MyStruct = MyStruct {
  myobject :: [Int],
  ...
} deriving (Generic)

instance FromJSON MyStruct where
  parseJSON = fmap (fromOR . modifyRField @"myobject" (\(MySpecialType i) -> i) . toOR')
            . genericParseJSON defaultOptions
```