# Aeson: Parse json object to list

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I would like to parse the values of a json object to a list.

Here's my current approach (simplified and the newtype is based on the results of: [Aeson: derive some (but not all) fields of a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53448958/aeson-derive-some-but-not-all-fields-of-a-struct) (means I need it)):

Json:

```
{"v1": 1, "v2": 2}
```

Wanted result:

```
Test [1,2]
```

Current approach:

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.HashMap.Strict (elems)

newtype Test = Test [Int]
instance FromJSON Test where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    mapM parseJSON (elems o)
```

Compilation error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[b0]’ with ‘Test’
  Expected type: aeson-1.1.2.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Parser Test
    Actual type: aeson-1.1.2.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Parser [b0]
• In the expression: mapM parseJSON (elems o)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mapM parseJSON (elems o)` returns `Parser [Int]`, but you need `Parser (Test [Int])`, so the correct way to do that is:

```
instance FromJSON Test where
    parseJSON (Object o) = Test <$> mapM parseJSON (elems o)
```

However, the type of argument of `parseJSON` is `Value`, the value of argument may not be `Object`, it can also be an `Array`, `String` or etc, so it is better to use `withObject` to check what is it as:

```
instance FromJSON Test where
    parseJSON val = withObject "Test" 
                               (\o -> Test <$> mapM parseJSON (elems o))
                               val
```

`withObject` will print a meaningful error message when the value of type `Value` is not `Object`.